# prooftrees - justification on one line

Tags: prooftrees

I use prooftrees to do tableau proofs and would like to be able to state the justification for line 2--4 using a bracket that spans all three lines and has the justification text to its right. The example with two lines depicted is that provided by Clea F. Rees (the author of prooftrees) in the manual, but I cannot figure out how to make the justification text to line up neatly, nor how to make it apply to more than two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,fit,backgrounds,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}
{}
[A \to (\bot \to \bot)  \mbox{, $-0$}, name=n1, 
[r011,
[A  \mbox{, $+1$},  just=$(\to_{-})$:n1, tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          \draw [thick, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] 
          (!1.south west -| just #1.west) ++(0,5pt) -- (just #1.north west);
        }{level()}
[\bot \to \bot  \mbox{, $-1$}, name=n2, just={}
]]]]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not familiar with the `prooftrees` package, but you can add `node[right]{$(\to_{-})$}` between `--` and `(just #1.north west)` to place the label on the brace.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you @SandyG!

Comment: @SandyG Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: You can reference nodes in the `tikz` code to get the brace over as many lines as you need. If you name the nodes, you can use those names with the regular anchors. Alternatively, you can use `forest` to specify nodes relevant to the current node or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `node` to the brace just like you would in plain Ti*k*Z using `node[right]{$(\to_{-})$}`.

Unrelated, but the `mbox`es are unnecessary if you enclose the contents in braces. For example, `{A,+1}` instead of `A  \mbox{, $+1$}`. This creates a "thin space" instead of an "interword space". If you like the bigger space you can use `{A,\ +1}`.

Finally, I used `yshift=5pt` as a coordinate option instead of `++(0,5pt)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,fit,backgrounds,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}
{}
[{A \to (\bot \to \bot),-0}, name=n1, 
[r011,
[{A,+1},  just={}:n1, tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          \draw [thick, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] 
          ([yshift=5pt]!1.south west -| just #1.west) --node[right]{$(\to_{-})$} ([yshift=5pt]just #1.north west);
        }{level()}
[{\bot \to \bot, -1}, name=n2, just={}
]]]]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```